# Retrieving and loading data from Storage

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am building an application and trying to retrieve data from server and display it separately. for this I am using Storage, in app.component.ts I have called the server.ts and stored it to a shared local service:

app.component.ts:

```
  constructor(platform: Platform, public jobsData: JobsData, public storage: Storage, public local: Local) {
       platform.ready().then(() => {
        // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
        // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
        Splashscreen.hide();

     jobsData.load().subscribe(res => {
        local.localData(res);
     });
  });
```

This is the local service:

```
@Injectable()
  export class Local {

    constructor(public storage: Storage) { }
       localData(data){
       this.setLocalData(data);
    }

    setLocalData(data){
     this.storage.set('data', JSON.stringify(data));
    };

    getLocalData(){
     return this.storage.get('data').then((value) => {
     return JSON.parse(value);
    });
   };
```

and Im displaying the data on a specific page/component in the constructor as follows:

```
  local.getLocalData().then((res) => {
    this.jobs = res;
    console.log(this.jobs)
  });
```

On web console it retrieves and displays the data instantly, However, when I build the .apk file and install it on Android and open it for the first time.... it does not load anything, until I exit the program and open it again!!!

I don't know why it does this.... Or perhaps if there is a better way to do this!! I am trying this way to reduce the loading time of retrieving data as well when the device is offline so it displays the last stored data on the local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root page needs to be called in device ready after you retrieve data. So in you app.component.ts move rootsPage to device ready and it should be fine. I hope it helps.